# Update LazyVGrid list

Tags: swiftui

I have a `LazyVGrid` list which need to be updated whenever a data is updated. The data is in a singleton class.

```
class BluetoothManager: NSObject {
    static let shared = BluetoothManager()
    @objc dynamic private(set) var stations: [BHStation] = []
}
```

And the list is

```
var body: some View {
    let columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? 2 : 1)
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 10, pinnedViews: [], content: {
            ForEach(BluetoothManager.shared.stations, id: \.peripheral.identifier) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    MainCell()
                } 
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I tried to use `ObservableObject` with `@Published`, or to use `@State`/`@Binding` but none of them worked.

How can I make the list get updated whenever `stations` is get updated? `@objc dynamic` is necessary to be used in the other `UIKit` classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your SwiftUI `View` to know to update, you should use an `ObservableObject` with a `@Published` property and store it as a `@ObservedObject` or `@StateObject`:

```
class BluetoothManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    static let shared = BluetoothManager()
    private override init() { }
    @Published var stations: [BHStation] = []
}
```

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject private var manager = BluetoothManager.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        let columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? 2 : 1)
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 10, pinnedViews: [], content: {
                ForEach(manager.stations, id: \.peripheral.identifier) { item in //<-- Here
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                        MainCell()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The `@Published` may interfere with your `@objc` requirement, but since you haven't given any information on how you use it in UIKit or why it's necessary, it's not possible to say directly what the fix is. You may need a different setter to use when interacting with it in UIKit.

Also, be aware that `@Published` won't update as expected unless the model type it is storing (`BHStation`) is a `struct`. If it's a class, you may need to call `objectWillChange` directly to get the `@Published` publisher to trigger correctly.